# Get timestamp of sent and received data using Python requests library

Tags: python, python-requests

using `requests` library of Python, is there any possibility to get the exact timestamp of received and sent data, e.g. headers or payload data?

Example:

```
import requests

url     = 'http://mytest.url'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'My Agent'}
payload = 'Hello World'

response = requests.post(url, payload, headers)

print response
```

Output (Note that headers and payload data may have different timestamps of reception!):

```
2019/10/09 13:00.05.12345 >> POST http://mytest.url HTTP/1.1
2019/10/09 13:00.05.67890 >> User-Agent: My Agent
2019/10/09 13:00.06.12345 >> Hello World
2019/10/09 13:00.10.12345 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2019/10/09 13:00.11.12345 << Connection: Keep Alive
2019/10/09 13:00.12.12345 << Hello My Agent
```

Greets,
Steve

Comment: Your response data will almost certainly be received in one big block.  Remember that TCP is a streaming protocol, not a packet protocol.  Even if the sender sends 32 bytes, then 16 bytes, then 128 bytes, you will usually receive it as a single read of 176 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

There is in fact a `response.elapsed` property that indicates how long the request took.

The best I think you can go about getting both the submission datetime and completed datetime is:

```
from datetime import datetime
import requests

url     = 'http://mytest.url'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'My Agent'}
payload = 'Hello World'

now = datetime.now()
response = requests.post(url, payload, headers)

elapsed = now + response.elapsed
```